# Special birthday

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, time

I made this challenge.

Aica will celebrate her birthday next week.

When she wrote the date format of her birthday in the form of ***M/D/YYYY***, she noticed that her birthday will fall in **a quarter** of a year that is **quarter of a perfect year**.

What date and day of the week is her birthday?

Hints:

> “year” means number.

> “A quarter” is the Month/Day.

Comment: What does “quarter of a perfect year” mean? Or is figuring that out part of the puzzle? Should this have the [tag:riddle] tag?

Comment: r/youngpeoplereddit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand the phrasing of the question but I'm going to guess that

> The second hint is interpreted literally so that "Month/Day = A quarter = 1/4" so her birthday is the **4th of January**. Notice this question was posted on the 5th but also the OP refers to the question as if it were first asked in the past so I think this is plausible.

For the other part

> Quarter of a perfect year puts me in mind of quarter of a year that is a perfect number. The only perfect number that would really fit our timeframe is 8128 and one quarter of that is **2032** so I think really that is the year that Aica gets excited about

So the full answer is probably

> 1/4/2032 - although her birthday falls on the 4th of January every year, in any case.